# How do I get the entire inner content of an XML node including element tags?

Tags: perl, xml-twig

Using [`XML::Twig`](http://p3rl.org/XML::Twig), is there a way to get the entire HTML of a node? I do not want the text of the node, but the entire HTML with tags and all.

input XML

```
<content> <p>blah blah <b> bla bla </b> </p>
<p> line 2 <i> test </i? </p>
</content>
```

Code

```
my $twig = new XML::Twig(
    TwigRoots    => {'content' => 1},
    TwigHandlers => $twig_handlers
);
my $twig_handlers = {'count/p' => \&count_ps};

sub count_ps {
    my ($twig, $test) = @_;
    $Data .= $test->text();
}
```

`$data` should show me the entire HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`xml_string` method](http://p3rl.org/XML::Twig#xml_string).

```
my $data;
XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        content => sub {
            my ($twig, $elt) = @_;
            $data = $elt->xml_string;
            $twig->purge;
        }
    }
)->parse('    <content> <p>blah blah <b> bla bla </b> </p>
    <p> line 2 <i> test </i> </p>
    </content>
')->purge;
```